What do game studios look for in entry level resumés for designers?
(Inspired by this question which was closed as unclear. I'm attempting to focus on one part of what that querant was asking.)
What do game studios look for when hiring entry level designers? Are there specific certifications or other credentials that can be acquired by students which will improve their chances of getting a job in the industry? If not, what should they spend their time on instead?

Richard Carrillo has given some great GDC talks on how he interviews designers and what he looks for in a candidate. I may follow up and add an answer based on this and my own experience when I have some time.

@DMGregory - Please do; I will hold off on accepting any answers for a few more days, and I would happily accept an answer with real experience to draw on. My own answer is based on secondhand knowledge - as a solo indie dev, I don't have much experience on either side of the interview desk.

The best resumés come with a portfolio of completed project(s)
There are no meaningful credentials for game designers. Even four-year degrees in game design from accredited institutions are viewed somewhat skeptically by most professionals I've spoken to. In the best-case scenario, the hiring manager might have gone through the same program and understand what it entails, but most of the time, such credentials aren't worth the paper they're printed on.
Instead, the best resumés are accompanied by a history which contains at least one completed project. A completed project demonstrates that the candidate understands the end-to-end process of development.
This portfolio should be readable without playing any games
It might be tempting to assume that the hiring manager will want to play the games on your portfolio; after all, conventional wisdom of game design says that you can't know if an idea is good or not until you've playtested it. However, most of the time, this isn't the case. The hiring manager (or whomever is filtering your resumé before then) often has very little time to evaluate each candidate - either because they have hundreds of resumés to sift through or because their primary job is to make games and they only have a couple hours a week to spend reviewing candidates.
Thus, a student should ensure that their portfolio contains screenshots, explanations, and possibly short video demos to show off the best parts of their work even for people who do not play the games.
Mods and level packs can also be portfolio pieces
While there are multi-disciplinary designers who will include whole games in their portfolio, that is not a requirement for all disciplines - mods and level packs can make great portfolio pieces. Many large studios hire entry level designers to fill out content after the more senior designers have designed the major systems. If a studio is looking for designers to write abilities for a roster of 100+ characters, an applicant whose portfolio includes mods which add new characters to an existing game would be of interest to them. Similarly, if a studio is building a large open world game with dungeons scattered around the map and they need people to design those dungeons, then they might be interested in a portfolio containing a level pack.
With all that said, a couple words of caution: First, your portfolio will be assessed for "culture-fit" as much as for competence. If a mod contains content which is illegal or offensive, that will likely overshadow everything else about the mod in the hiring manager's eyes. Leave such things out of your portfolio. Second, game development is a small world. It is very likely that some of the people who see your resumé will also know someone who worked on the game the mods target. If the mod has an antagonistic relationship with the original developers (such as private servers for an MMO), hiring managers will take that into account.

I would disagree with the "game development is a small world" assertion. There are some major studios that dominate a large chunk of the market, but even these are often divided into numerous branches world-wide. It seems unlikely, for example, that a hiring manager reviewing applications at Bethesda would personally know Ubisoft developers working in Milan. And that's completely disregarding the countless thousands of indie studios worldwide. There are over 100,000 games on Steam and over 200,000 on Android. This isn't a small world and these developers can't possible all know each other.

@Kevin - I think the world's small enough that my recommendation to not advertise antagonistic history in your portfolio still holds. While it may be unlikely that a hiring manager for Bethesda would personally know any particular Ubisoft developer working in Milan, it's much more plausible that the hiring manager might know at least one person who used to work for Ubisoft in Milan - so if someone did something that antagonizes all of Ubisoft Milan, they should leave that off their resumé and out of their portfolio, just in case.

I don't dispute the advice - obviously a candidate should leave anything that could reflect poorly on themself out of their resume. On a tangent, it might be worth elaborating a little on "content which is illegal" - some people, especially younger developers getting into modding, don't even realize that it's illegal to do things like  make unauthorized use of someone else's intellectual property in a mod. They assume that if they aren't charging money, then no laws have been broken or intellectual property infringed upon.
